# Find expectation $E\exp(X_1+X_2)\mathbf{I}_{\{X_1<X_2\}}.$

Tags: expected-value

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ two independent random variables. The PDF of $X_i$ is $f_{X_i}(x_i)$.

Ho we can find the following expectation 
$$E\exp(X_1+X_2)\mathbf{I}_{\{X_1<X_2\}}.$$

Is it

\begin{align}
E\exp(X_1+X_2)\mathbf{I}_{\{X_1<X_2\}}&=Ee^{X_1}e^{X_2}\mathbf{I}_{\{X_1<X_2\}}\\
&=\int_{x_2=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{x_2}f_{X_2}(x_2)\left(\int_{x_1=-\infty}^{x_2}e^{x_1}f_{X_1}(x_1)dx_1\right)dx_2.
\end{align}
Thanks.

Comment: What does $EZ[A]$ mean when $Z$ is a random variable and $A$ is an event?.

Comment: Believe me I do not know.

Comment: I do not mean $E[Z|A]$. I mean the expected value  of product of two random variables, $X_1$ and $X_2$ where $X_1<X_2$.

Comment: Is it $$E\left[X_1\times X_2 [X_1<X_2]\right]=\int_{x_2=-\infty}^{\infty}x_2f_{X_2}(x_2)\int_{x_1=-\infty}^{x_2}x_1f_{X_1}(x_1)dx_1dx_2$$?

Comment: I think that is correct but the notation used in the question is not satndard.

Comment: How is the standard so I can correct it?Thanks..

Comment: It is $EX_1X_2I_{\{X_1 <X_2\}}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91531/discussion-between-monir-and-kavi-rama-murthy).

Comment: I try but I think is not the correct answer..

Comment: I forget EXpntial function so I get $Ee^{X_1}e^{X_2}\mathbf{I}_{\{X_1<X_2\}}.$

Comment: The final answer is correct.